# Cannot bind double with Android databinding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I have a class that extends `BaseObservable`, this class contains the double value

This is an example :

```
public class BindedValue extends BaseObservable {

public double value;


public TextWatcher setValue = new TextWatcherAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        value = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
    }
  };
}
```

Then I got xml

```
<data class="net.example.util.Value">

            <variable
        name="BindedValue"
        type="net.makereal.makerealmaquette.domain.BindedValue"/>
```

```
    <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Value"
                android:addTextChangedListener="@{BindedValue.setValue}"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="@{BindedValue.value}"/>
```

When I try to run or build the app I get this error :

```
Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:text' with parameter type double on android.widget.EditText.
```

However when I change the type to int the app builds with no issue.

Is there a way to bind a double?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> However when I change the type to int the app builds with now issue.

Yes, but it will fail at runtime. `setText(int)` expects a string resource ID, not an arbitrary `int`.

> Is there way to bind double?

```
android:text="@{Double.toString(BindedValue.value)}"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is another option for converting objects to `String`:

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(BindedValue.value)}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax also works:

```
android:text='@={""+item.value}'
```

and it can be inverted by adding a `String` setter:

```
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.setValue(Double.valueOf(value));
}
```